# Форматированный ввод десятичного числа на React

Tags: html5, reactjs

[image: как исправить это баг?]

код:
<input type="tel"  onChange={investValueHandle} value={investValue.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")}/>
хотел получить результат 10,000,000 но у меня выходит  1,0,0,0,0000

Comment: В чем проблема/вопрос ?

Comment: там должно вывести значение "10,000,000"

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @МурадилКойчубеков добавьте в вопрос описание, что и как у вас работает, и какого результата необходимо достичь

Comment: описал что у меня выходить и что должен получить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из коментария `должно вывести значение "10,000,000"` набросал рабочий вариант кода:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const inputChangeHandler = ({ target }) => {
    setValue(target.value.replace(/\D*/g, ""));
  };

  const getValue = () => {
    return value.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, "$1,");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={getValue()} onChange={inputChangeHandler} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: спасибо большое